# Toggle Switch color Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, toggleswitch

I'm creating an app where on my main page I have a list with a ToggleSwitch control on each row but the control doesn't appear on the phone emulator. The XAML for the ToggleSwitch control is as below:

```
<toolkit:ToggleSwitch x:Name="ToggleSwitch" IsChecked="false" Content="Content Goes here" Checked="switch_Unchecked" Unchecked="switch_Unchecked" BorderBrush="black" Background="Black" Width="200"/>
```

When I click on that code, it shows me that:

[image]

So I believe that the control with BorderBrush=black and Background=Black is at the right place but it doesn't appear... 
May somebody helps me with that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the color of your Grid Background color? There might be some problem with that too. Try applying the following style for the Toggle Switch.

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <toolkit:ToggleSwitch Margin="12,0" Content="Live Update" Background="White" Foreground="Black" Style="{StaticResource FixedToggleSwitchStyle}"/>
</Grid>
```

And the style is,

```
<Style x:Key="FixedToggleSwitchButtonStyle" TargetType="toolkitPrimitives:ToggleSwitchButton">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="SwitchForeground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkitPrimitives:ToggleSwitchButton">
                <Border x:Name="Root" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CacheMode="BitmapCache" Opacity="{TemplateBinding Opacity}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchBottom"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="ThumbCenter"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Root"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.05" To="Unchecked"/>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.05" To="Checked"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="69" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundTranslation">
                                        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                            <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Exponent="15"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    </DoubleAnimation>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="69" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="ThumbTranslation">
                                        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                            <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Exponent="15"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    </DoubleAnimation>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Dragging"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundTranslation"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="ThumbTranslation"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid x:Name="SwitchRoot" Background="Transparent" Height="95" Width="136">
                        <Grid x:Name="SwitchTrack" Width="89">
                            <Grid x:Name="SwitchBottom" Background="{TemplateBinding SwitchForeground}" Height="34">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="SwitchBackground" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="77">
                                    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                        <TranslateTransform x:Name="BackgroundTranslation"/>
                                    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                </Rectangle>
                                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" BorderThickness="3">
                                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="4"/>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                            <Border x:Name="SwitchThumb" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="4,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="38" Margin="-4,0" Width="28">
                                <Border.RenderTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="ThumbTranslation"/>
                                </Border.RenderTransform>
                                <Border x:Name="ThumbCenter" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" BorderThickness="2" Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="FixedToggleSwitchStyle" TargetType="toolkit:ToggleSwitch">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyLight}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="SwitchForeground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:ToggleSwitch">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CacheMode="BitmapCache" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Header"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Content"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid Margin="12,5,12,42">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="Header" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneSubtleBrush}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsTabStop="False" Margin="-1,0,0,0" Opacity="{TemplateBinding Opacity}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="Content" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsTabStop="False" Margin="-1,1,0,-7" Opacity="{TemplateBinding Opacity}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        <toolkitPrimitives:ToggleSwitchButton x:Name="Switch" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Column="1" Margin="-22,-29,-24,-28" Opacity="{TemplateBinding Opacity}" Grid.RowSpan="2" SwitchForeground="{TemplateBinding SwitchForeground}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Style="{StaticResource FixedToggleSwitchButtonStyle}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Change your Background color and Foreground color as per your needs in Toggle Switch.

Answer (score 1):

Have either one of these property, `Background` or the `BorderBrush`.

Why don't you try it this way?

xaml:

```
<ToggleSwitch x:Name="toggleSwitch1" Header="ToggleSwitch" 
          OnContent="On" OffContent="Off" 
          Toggled="ToggleSwitch_Toggled"/>

private void ToggleSwitch_Toggled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
// Add code to perform some action here.
}
```

Have a look at [this](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-toggleswitch-in-depth--key-concepts-and-api) too. Is that the one you're using from the `Toolkit` or what?

Hope it helps!